# Carrierwave does not create upload folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

My main problem is, that when uploading via carrierwave the file isn't truly uploaded.

My console output:

```
#<OptionPic id: 4, image_url: "game_of_thrones___tyrion_lannister_by_stanbos-d79k...", created_at: "2015-08-07 06:08:01", updated_at: "2015-08-07 06:08:01", option_id: 12>]>
```

The call to the image is following

```
-@product.options.each do |option|
          -option.option_pics.each do |op|
            =image_tag op.image_url.to_s
```

If I inspect the element on my webpage, this is what I get:

`<img src="/images/game_of_thrones___tyrion_lannister_by_stanbos-d79k0u9_modified.jpg" alt="Game of thrones   tyrion lannister by stanbos d79k0u9 modified">`

However settings on the uploader are as following:

```
class ProductImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

# Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
include CarrierWave::RMagick
# include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

# Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
storage :file
# storage :fog

# Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
# This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be    mounted:
def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Needless to say I have neither an image in the assets/images folder nor a public/uploads folder created.

This works perfectly on my other project (public/uploads folder is created with the same syntax as above), where images are stored as a separate model. In my current project I want them as a sub-option for a product class.

The structure is following:

models - product, option, optionpic(ture)

A product can have many options and in turn an option can have many pictures. For example - product is a T-Shirt. Options are: material and color. For each color I want a different picture of the shirt.

This is why I have everything in my ProductsController:

```
  Class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_product, only: [:show]

  def show
  end

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
    @option = @product.options.new
    @option_pic = OptionPic.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.create(product_params)
    @option = @product.options.create(option_params)
    @option.product_id = @product.id
    @option.save

    @option_pic = @option.option_pics.create(pic_params)
    @option_pic.option_id = @option.id

    flash[:success] = "Product successfully created!"
    redirect_to products_path
  end

  private

    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :advertising_text, :fancy_quote)
    end

    def option_params
      params.require(:option).permit(:size, :weight, :price, :material, :product_id)
    end

    def pic_params
      params.require(:option_pic).permit(:image_url, :option_id)
    end

    def find_product
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

My optionpic(ture) model:

```
class OptionPic < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :product_image, ProductImageUploader
    belongs_to :option
end
```

I think I am making just some dumb newbie mistake, but after hours of search I just can't figure out what is wrong.

## Edit

I figured out two things - I used image_url instead of picture_image and forgot to actually save the option_picture values in the controller, i.e. `@option_pic.save`

How ever now there is no data transmission when uploading:

```
SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "option_pics" ("product_image", "option_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["product_image", nil], ["option_id", 18], ["created_at", "2015-08-07 08:03:28.559319"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-07 08:03:28.559319"]]
```

I updated every value from :image_url to :product_image (in the view, in the pic_params etc.)

## Edit 2

As requested, my upload form:

```
%h1 Create new product

=form_for @product, url: products_path do |f|
    %p
        =f.label :title
        =f.text_field :title
        %br
        =f.label :description
        =f.text_area :description
        %br
        =f.label :advertising_text
        =f.text_area :advertising_text
        %br
        =f.label :fancy_quote
        =f.text_area :fancy_quote

    %p
        = fields_for @option do |o|
            =o.label :price
            =o.text_field :price
            %br
            =o.label :size
            =o.text_field :size
            %br
            =o.label :weight
            =o.text_field :weight
            %br
            =o.label :material
            =o.text_field :material
    %p
        = fields_for @option_pic, html: { multipart: true } do |op|
            = op.label 'Upload image'
            = op.file_field :product_image
    =f.submit
```

## Edit 3

As requested, my log parameters

```
Started POST "/products" for ::1 at 2015-08-07 12:25:31 +0300
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DOeZMvYpdoVmZRpsGmg2Gr9LIc9RYaS1KT1vdfhXI2BJaV3pPZZbZN8PJnvwQAig8wLPpIUORuf7Kjcw3BE6Zg==", "product"=>{"title"=>"fafa", "description"=>"", "advertising_text"=>"", "fancy_quote"=>""}, "option"=>{"price"=>"", "size"=>"", "weight"=>"", "material"=>""}, "option_pic"=>{"product_image"=>"level-3-on-rails-for-zombies-2-0eaaf0109f83459c5aedef30bdf8bd96.png"}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("title", "description", "advertising_text", "fancy_quote", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "fafa"], ["description", ""], ["advertising_text", ""], ["fancy_quote", ""], ["created_at", "2015-08-07 09:25:31.365739"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-07 09:25:31.365739"]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "options" ("size", "material", "product_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["size", ""], ["material", ""], ["product_id", 29], ["created_at", "2015-08-07 09:25:31.369112"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-07 09:25:31.369112"]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "option_pics" ("product_image", "option_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["product_image", nil], ["option_id", 21], ["created_at", "2015-08-07 09:25:31.372492"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-07 09:25:31.372492"]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
```

Comment: Show the code (ERB) of your upload form.

Comment: Show what parameters your request really receives – copy the line from `log/development.log`. It seems that you have an error in nested parameters handling.

Comment: Added them as well (image url appears to be in the parameters hash)

Comment: Yup, I was right. Added an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing your `params` value properly. The following will fix that:

```
def pic_params
  params.require(:option_pic).require(:product_image)
end
```

Also, you have to make your OptionPic belonging to your Option when you build it:

```
def new
  @product = Product.new
  @option = @product.options.new
  @option_pic = @option.option_pics.new
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't I nest the requires too? Something like that: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html
Because right now I'm getting this error:

`ActionController::ParameterMissing at /products
param is missing or the value is empty: option`

in 

`def option_params
      params.require(:product).require(:option).permit(:size, :weight, :price, :material, :product_id)
    end`

Comment: @mohnstrudel I'm sorry, I was wrong about nested hashes. You should change `image_url` to `product_image`, but we are not over that issue just yet. Your client doesn't seem to send file. Do you have some javascript on page which intercepts uploads? Like upload progress report plugins or something?

Comment: Yes, I already renamed all image_url to product_image.

And I do use a bootstrap template, however I tried submitting the form with javascript completely disabled, still without result.

I remember when I had image_url instead of product_image my app would at least save the url, e.g. 
`/images/game_of_thrones___tyrion_lannister_by_stanbos-d79k0u9_modified.jpg`

Comment: @mohnstrudel Updated my answer with another fix. That may be the last one, and maybe we will find even more.

Comment: This is utterly strange - at first I changed my code just as you suggested. Nothing happened to my uploads. Then I added an avatar column to my products table (just to check if the most standard upload will work), created an avatar uploader and two file fields on the "new" page - one for product.avatar and the old one for product_pic. Now both file are uploaded!

Answer (score 0):

If someone encounters same problem, I will post my solution - I decided to recreate this system using nested attributes, now everything work fine!

So here I have my 3 models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to  :category 
    belongs_to  :subcategory
    has_many    :options

    has_and_belongs_to_many :product_sizes

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :options

end
```

The option class, which is the child of a product

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to  :product
    has_many    :option_pics

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :option_pics
end
```

And finally the option_pic, a child of an option

```
class OptionPic < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :product_image, ProductImageUploader
    belongs_to :option
end
```

In the products controller my new and create actions look as following:

```
  def new
    @product = Product.new
    option = @product.options.build
    option_pic = option.option_pics.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    if @product.save!
      flash[:success] = "Product successfully created!"
      redirect_to products_path
    end
  end

  private

    def product_params
        params.require(:product).permit(
        :title, :description, :advertising_text, :fancy_quote, :category_id, 
        options_attributes: [:size, :weight, :price, :material, :product_id, 
          option_pics_attributes: [:product_image, :option_id]])
end

def find_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

The string params are double nested, which is important. Also important is the structure for the form_for helper. I did not refactor it, so right now it is one big list. The structure there is very important, I had my fields for option_pic intended on the level of the "f" variable, which was crucial and no images were uploaded.

```
=form_for @product, url: products_path do |f|
    %p
        =f.label :title
        =f.text_field :title
        %br
        =f.label :description
        =f.text_area :description
        %br
        =f.label :advertising_text
        =f.text_area :advertising_text
        %br
        =f.label :fancy_quote
        =f.text_area :fancy_quote
        %br
        =f.label :category_id
        =f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :title, { prompt: 'Please select category' }
        %br
        =f.label 'Product Size'
        =f.collection_check_boxes(:product_size_ids, ProductSize.all, :id, :size)

    %p
        = f.fields_for :options do |builder|
            =builder.label :price
            =builder.text_field :price
            %br
            =builder.label :size
            =builder.text_field :size
            %br
            =builder.label :weight
            =builder.text_field :weight
            %br
            =builder.label :material
            =builder.text_field :material
            %br
            =builder.fields_for :option_pics do |op|
                = op.label 'Upload image'
                = op.file_field :product_image
    =f.submit
```

And voila, a wonderful commit:

```
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("title", "description", "advertising_text", "fancy_quote", "category_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "builder"], ["description", ""], ["advertising_text", ""], ["fancy_quote", ""], ["category_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-08-11 11:34:11.618298"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-11 11:34:11.618298"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "options" ("size", "price", "material", "product_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["size", ""], ["price", 555], ["material", ""], ["product_id", 82], ["created_at", "2015-08-11 11:34:11.619678"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-11 11:34:11.619678"]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "option_pics" ("product_image", "option_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["product_image", "b3c839_bd43d840e031469495137fa74e31faf4.jpg_srz_428_428_75_22_0.5_1.2_75_jpg_srz"], ["option_id", 66], ["created_at", "2015-08-11 11:34:11.620837"], ["updated_at", "2015-08-11 11:34:11.620837"]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
```